# import cv2 Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Tags: python, opencv

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install opencv-python
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (4.5.1.48)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from opencv-python) (1.16.2)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 3.8.4 (default, Sep 16 2020, 00:40:58)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import cv2
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
> > > import cv
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv'

KeyboardInterrupt

> > > 

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting); make sure you show the code exactly as you actually have it (with proper formatting); make sure you use English sentences to explain the problem; and make sure you **ask a question**, starting with a question word like "why" or "how" and ending with a question mark (`?`).

Comment: But here's a hint: look closely at `Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (4.5.1.48)`. What version of Python is that talking about? Look closely at `Python 3.8.4 (default, Sep 16 2020, 00:40:58) [GCC 8.3.0] on linux`. What version of Python is that talking about? Do you see why this causes a problem?